# As an ambitious female PhD student, should I avoid dating people?

Tags: gender, two-body-problem

I am a female PhD student, studying computer science at a top school in the heart of Silicon Valley.  I have a wonderful boyfriend who probably never wants to leave the Bay Area because he is (a) a software engineer, and (b) owns a very expensive house.  So if I go into academia I probably have to break up with him, and I think I would encounter similar problems with almost any other guy I date.

Would it be better to get married and take a nice job in industry, or go into academia and never date anyone?  I only sort of want to go into academia, but I can't shake the nagging feeling of being limited.  It's like a voice in my head saying "you could be so much more successful, if you wanted to."  I do not want to be like the other ambitious women who reach a glass ceiling and have to compromise on their ambitions because of their partners.

Comment: there isn't any answer to this question, people don't have a crystal glass. You might be more career focused now, then maybe your mother instinct kicks in and you will want to settle down or have a life more centered around personal relationships.

Comment: Or else, you settle for a less ambitious boyfriend who is ready to move with you and has fewer priorities to cater for. Alternatively, sometimes academic couples get double-offers if one of the partners is very strong. A totalistic decision as you suggest in your question is almost always wrong without a qualifying condition. But, yes, dating will be harder for you than others if you constrain yourself to only consider boyfriends at or above your level career -or finance-wise.

Comment: Asking as a male, but what does being female have to do with it? Many people are probably concerned about limiting their career options because they have an SO, including myself. I have not often heard the glass ceiling equated with having a partner.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Women are just generally expected to compromise a lot more on these sorts of things than men are, e.g.  https://hbr.org/2014/12/rethink-what-you-know-about-high-achieving-women "More than half the men in Generation X and the Baby Boom said that when they left HBS, they expected that their careers would take priority over their spouses’ or partners’. ... Meanwhile, the vast majority of women across racial groups and generations anticipated that their careers would rank equally with those of their partners."

Comment: Are you a GenXer? Is your question, then, if a potential partner would expect you to sacrifice your academic goals for them? In any partnership, someone's goals are going to have to be compromised for the other at some point.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I wouldn't say this guy is above my level (and I'm not sure why you assume that I'm dating "up"), but that doesn't mean he doesn't have preferences of his own.  Even someone who is extremely unambitious may want to stay in the area (e.g. if they have friends or family there).  No one really wants to be dragged around by their partners no matter what "level" they're at

Comment: I'm sympathetic to your quandary, but without knowing your relative preferences/values, how could you possibly expect a good answer to this question? This question seems better directed to someone who knows you, a trusted adviser, or failing that perhaps a trained therapist.

Comment: If your boyfriend isn't willing to commit to your relationship as equals, that's a problem in itself. If he is, then he wouldn't let his own preferences or the inertia of his current job outweigh your career and your desires. (In particular, if he isn't willing to even consider moving elsewhere in order for you to pursue your career, he isn't really committed to an equal partnership with you.)

Comment: @TomChurch I haven't talked to him about this and I'm not sure if he would move or not.  But because he is a software engineer and most of the good engineering jobs are here, I think his job prospects would be a lot worse if he moved (and also he owns a house so moving would be a hassle).  I think it would be unfair and selfish of me if I asked him to give up his job and his house and move to a town in the middle of nowhere.  It's just something I would never want to ask someone to do

Comment: ... although this question got on-hold-ed, I think it has more genuine/objective content than many people might understand. In any case, addressing the questioner, "yes..." you are right to think in these terms. The entire ambient "professional (academic and otherwise)" structure basically ignores human relationships, regardless of gender, preferences, etc. E.g., it's clearly best to have an essentially monastic lifestyle... moving wherever the job is, leaving friends (if any?) behind... repeatedly... Moving to "wherever" for The Job?!? (not only academic...) By incredible luck, I myself...

Comment: ... "fell" into a major metropolitan area, in a not-insane part of the U.S. By accident. Other "good jobs" could/would have taken me and others into the "islands of sanity" that, at best, are the universities "out in the middle of nowhere", and so on. No, I would not want to be, and I would not expect any significant other of mine, to be a pizza waitron in an "island" so one of us could "be high-status".

Comment: You didn't mention your age but it certainly affects your options a lot.  If you're 24 and two years into a PhD program, you can reasonably be single now and through a postdoc, land a tenure-track position and date in that geographic area so that neither of you plans to move in the next several decades, and start a family in your early 30s.  If you're 30 already, that approach is less feasible, and having family requires putting that into motion while you're still expecting to move in the future for career reasons.

Comment: In any case, you definitely should get your boyfriend's input.  You don't have to phrase it as asking a favor.  Simply "Are you planning to make this area home for the next 20 years?" and "Do you think you would be as happy living across the country?" or "Are there other companies you are interested in working for?"  If you let him bring up "where we're together" in his answer (or not), you don't need to feel unfair and selfish.  Trying to make the decision unilaterally is far more selfish.

Comment: Remember too that you could put down roots right there with him, giving up an academic career, and still have to move because "nice house" does not equate to "good school district" or all the other factors that make a good environment for children.

Comment: @girl You are right, I was making assumptions. But from the question, it seemed that you had already his inputs which, as you clarified later, you didn't. I think it is fair to discuss it with him, as this is a double decision. I am afraid, however, that today it is more likely than not that good success in academia is linked to a single lifestyle (and that increasingly affects men, too). In some cases known to me long-distance relationships actually work out, and surprisingly well; so, do not cut yourself off from options. Discuss with your boyfriend, weigh, decide, & redecide when necessary.

Comment: I wager that @girl will break up with her boyfriend in the near future and this will be a non-issue soon.

Comment: @ProfSantaClaus The issue is not with this boyfriend, it's with all boyfriends.  If I broke up with this boyfriend, most people I date would also not want to move to the middle of nowhere to support an academic career, but would be happy to stay in the Bay Area, where I could have a good career in industry.  That's why I'm asking more about dating in general than about this specific guy.  Although because this guy is a lot older than me, he has particularly legit location constraints (i.e. a house)

Comment: @girl your life comes first - if you want to go after academia goals, then go for it.  I've met too many women, significantly older than me, that divorced their husbands 7 or 8 years later.  All of them wish they could have those years back and do things differently.  And that the money gotten from the divorce is not at all worth the time that they lost.  Marriage is too impermanent these days.

Comment: Not going to write an answer but: I've pretty much given up on it at this point, for both personal and work-related reasons. The work related ones are like you're saying: we're going to have to move around a lot if we are successful in academia. I couldn't ask or expect a partner to follow me around the world, nor do I think I'll ever find someone willing to. I'm not interested in having kids which is a dealbreaker for some high % of potential partners. I also just don't have the time. But I don't think you should not date FOR THE JOB only. Why should we have to give up more than anyone else?

Comment: That said, you should never ever give up your career for a partner. That is how resentment is bred.

It's possible to have and maintain a relationship in academia. It just isn't easy and it requires a lot of hard work and compromise.

Comment: If this question was reframed and placed in a more general context (how to manage personal constraints with a research career, particularly from a female perspective), it would certainly be a good fit for SE.

Comment: Way after the fact, but software engineering jobs are available in MANY places...  It's one of the most portable careers.  And much of the high quality work isn't in the Bay area.

Comment: I am male and just finished a PhD program in CS.  I did not date; there was not time.  Business or academia, it does not matter.  What matters is being able to come up with the right answers.  "Everybody who ever made it had a mentor."  Find one or more people who are willing to lead you to success in their environment.  Just keep calling, pushing, asking until you find someone, relatively high in the organization, who is willing to take you under their wing.

Comment: @girl pursue the relationship and enjoy yourselves. If you ever have to move. Tell him you will have to move. If he seems interested in following you. Problem Solved.